# Complex python dictionary ordering

Tags: python, sorting

So I have a list of values that I need to list by two elements.
Element one should sort the values based on the order in the list. There will be duplicates.
Element two should sort the duplicate based on an INT value. Here's what I have so far, but I'm just having trouble piecing it together.

Items to sort

```
unsorted_list = [
{ "key": 1, "group": "third"},
{ "key": 2, "group": "second"},
{ "key": 3, "group": "first"},
{ "key": 4, "group": "second"},
{ "key": 5, "group": "third"},
{ "key": 6, "group": "first"},
]
```

Element One

```
group_order = [ "first", "second", "third"]
```

Element Two:
Simply order the key in ASC order

Goal: Sorted first by the "group", second by the "key"

```
sorted_list = [
{ "key": 3, "group": "first"},
{ "key": 6, "group": "first"},
{ "key": 2, "group": "second"},
{ "key": 4, "group": "second"},
{ "key": 1, "group": "third"},
{ "key": 5, "group": "third"},
]
```

What I have so far:

```
sorted_list = sorted(
  unsorted_list,
  key = lambda i: (
     group_list[i.group] <- this isn't working
  ),
  i.key
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
out = sorted(unsorted_list, key=lambda k: (group_order.index(k["group"]), k["key"]))

# pretty print to screen:
from pprint import pprint
pprint(out)
```

Prints:

```
[{'group': 'first', 'key': 3},
 {'group': 'first', 'key': 6},
 {'group': 'second', 'key': 2},
 {'group': 'second', 'key': 4},
 {'group': 'third', 'key': 1},
 {'group': 'third', 'key': 5}]
```